# check if the field value exists in the database by javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

check if the field value exists in the database by `javascript`

Is it possible?

maybe something like this ..

```
search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE name = 'name' AND title = 'title'");
if(@mysql_num_rows(search) > 0){
```

Comment: Server is server, JavaScript is client. You need for example AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is IMPOSSIBLE to comunicate with any type of server in javascript. IMPOSSIBLE don't even try to search something. You need other languages like php ( reccomended ), java, asp...
Check tutorials for connecting with php:

[PHP mssql server connection tutorial](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mssql_database.php)

Comment: While this is true, it's worth pointing out that ajax is not a separate language from javascript -- ajax is (among other things) a technique in the javascript language for interacting with server-side scripts. As is, your answer could be a bit confusing to the uninitiated...